# is there someway to sharding in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have two questions about how to shard in clickhouse.

Q1. 
  Is it necessary to use a distributed engine for sharding in clickhouse?

Q2. 
  I wonder if sharding is possible according to the criteria that I set, not automatically distributed according to the weight of the shard.

```
Example.
 - If id is 1, it is stored in shard1.
 - If id is 2, it is stored in shard2.
 - If id is 3, it is stored in shard3.



I understand the sharding through the distribution engine as follows.
- distributed engine use the cluster defined in the config.xml file.
- It is automatically distributed to the shard according to the weight of the shard.
```

Thank you for reading my question. I look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Q1. Is it necessary to use a distributed engine for sharding in clickhouse?

Yes. Distributed engine knows how to distribute queries to local tables spread over shards and replicas. Without this you would need to run the queries on each shard and assemble the results yourself.

> Q2. I wonder if sharding is possible according to the criteria that I set, not automatically distributed according to the weight of the shard.

Yes. There are two ways to write data to your shards.

1. Insert through the distributed table.  ClickHouse will distribute to the local table(s) using the sharding key.
2. Write directly to the local tables.  In this case it's up to you to decide how to distribute data.  Many installations use this approach because it allows higher performance by going directly to the underlying table.

The distributed engine is really just a gateway to local tables, which is why #2 works.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but But I have three more questions.

1. Is it true that sharding key can't be anything other than a constant value or a column of table?

2. When data distibutes with a shading key, can we predict which shard the data is insert?

3. If each shard has the same weight, how should we set the sharding key for equal distribution of each shard?